# In either web3 or ethers, how do I monitor an address' transactions calling specific methods?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, web3.py, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor an address each time it calls "Transfer" or "Notify Reward Amount". And if there is a match, print the info of said transaction. Both interact with ERC20s.

First I'd like to try with old transactions to make sure it works, and then I'll try to monitor in real time.

Any idea of how to do it? Maybe connecting to a block explorer's API would be better?

Answer (score 0):

First, install the web3.js library:

```
npm install web3
```

Import the web3 library and set up a connection to the Ethereum network:

```js
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/YOUR-INFURA-API-KEY');
```

Create a function to fetch past events:

```js
async function getPastEvents(address, eventName, fromBlock, toBlock) {
  const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
  const events = await contract.getPastEvents(eventName, {
    fromBlock: web3.utils.numberToHex(fromBlock),
    toBlock: web3.utils.numberToHex(toBlock),
  });
  return events;
}
```

Call the `getPastEvents` function with the target address, event names ("Transfer" and "Notify Reward Amount"), and the block range you want to search:

```js
(async () => {
  const address = '0x...'; // The address you want to monitor
  const fromBlock = 12345678; // The starting block number
  const toBlock = 'latest'; // You can use 'latest' to get events up to the current block

  const transferEvents = await getPastEvents(address, 'Transfer', fromBlock, toBlock);
  const rewardEvents = await getPastEvents(address, 'Notify Reward Amount', fromBlock, toBlock);

  console.log('Transfer events:', transferEvents);
  console.log('Reward events:', rewardEvents);
})();
```

To monitor the address in real-time, you can use a tool like [Infura's WebSocket API](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/wss/ethereum-websockets) to receive event updates as they occur.

Replace `'YOUR-INFURA-API-KEY'` with your actual Infura API key, and update the `address` and `abi` variables with the target contract's address and ABI.